# How do I create distributions with different dependencies using Gradle application/distribution plugin?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am building a small Kotlin project in IntelliJ, Idea, and trying to figure out how to create multiple tar/zip files with customizations for each OS I want to support.

It seems like the distribution plugin (which is included when you use the application plugin) is the right direction,  but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to do what I want.

I have read the documentation on the plugin, which can be found [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html), but it's not really clear to me how to accomplish what I want to do.

Here is an example build.gradle that shows at least the idea of what I want to do, that is to have a base application setup and then have some minor tailoring for each of the 3 OSs.

For example each of the 3 OSs need a unique version of the SWT library. The macos version needs a specific JVM setting, and for the linux version, I need to tailor the startup script to add some environment variables.

Is this possible with the distribution plugin?  If not can someone suggest a different solution?

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.2.61'
}

apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "MainKt"

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    // my common required repos
}

dependencies {
    // my common dependencies    
}

distributions {
    macos {
        contents { from 'src' }
        applicationDefaultJvmArgs.push("-XstartOnFirstThread")
        dependencies {
            implementation "org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64:4.5.2"
        }
    }
    linux {
        contents { from 'src' }
        dependencies {
            implementation "org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64:4.5.2"
        }
        startScripts.doLast {
            def lines = unixScript.text.readLines()
            println lines.add(1, '# add some stuff')
            println lines.add(2, '# add some more stuff')
            unixScript.text = lines.join("\n")
        }
    }
    windows {
        contents { from 'src' }
        dependencies {
            implementation "org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64:4.5.2"
        }
    }
}



compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

### Update

This is what I am doing now, but I would like to improve on this.

I have a variable

```
def deploy = false
if (!deploy) {
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs.push("-XstartOnFirstThread")
    dependencies {
        implementation "org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64:4.5.2"
    }
} else {
    dependencies {
        implementation "org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64:4.5.2"
    }
    startScripts.doLast {
        def lines = unixScript.text.readLines()
        println lines.add(1, 'export foo=foo')
        println lines.add(2, 'export bar=bar')
    }
}
```

Right now I develop on my mac and set deploy to false.  When I want to generate the distribution for linux I set deploy to true.  I could add more code and do the same thing for windows, but I would like to just generate all the code in one task, and have it in different tar/zip files.

Comment: Do you have any project to try it out?

Comment: The above is from an active project I am working on ... I just added the distributions part and removed the noise of all my actually common includes.  What I get in the tar/zip files is just the src folder contents, but I really want each to be a fully compiled version of the project, just with the indented customizations.

Comment: Will the jar files (dependencies) included into the distribution? Also is there any abstraction above it? I mean, how do you use it in the code? Via a common interface?

Comment: I added an update that shows how I am partially handling this today. Yes I expect all the jar files to be in the distributions. The abstraction is really at the swt level,  each swt jar contains the same widgets but different interfaces to the native widget set.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/52744893) you can find what I've reached so far. Unfortunately now idea where should I go further. Could you please have a look at it? I guess together we can make it satisfying for you.

Comment: Thanks @Opal I will try and play around with you posted and see if I can make more progress

Comment: Cool, let me know about the results.

Comment: And, does it work?

Comment: Not yet,  did not seem to with my project, but I just created a new project and I think it does work,  so give me a little time to try again with my project.

Comment: Sure, waiting for the result then :)

Comment: The problem I ran into is this:  While the contents { with  ... from configurations.macos }} stuff _does_ get the jar into the distribution jar, that's really all it does. For example if you add System.out.println(SWT.CHECK);  (SWT.CHECK is just a constant int) I think you would see what the problem I have.  No version of SWT is added to the External Libraries so it can't find SWT.  If I add one the the dependencies it will compile, but then I get that one in all the distribution jars.  I will post an answer with what I tried and my current workaround.

Comment: Yup, this is what I partially expected. There should be also a version of SWT added for development and dependant on the OS developer is working on. Notice that none of added configurations extends `implementation`.

Comment: exacly.  I will post my workaround as answer,  it does what I want for now maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: I've updated my GH repository, could you please have a look at it once again?

Comment: Or maybe, whatever.. I've used `compileOnly` along with `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os` to determine the dependeny that should be added for compilation only - I guess it solves you problem. No points this time, however I learned a lot. However, with my solution you can build all three distros with single command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opal provided some very good suggestions in the question comments that I tried, but in the end, I was not able to really get what I wanted.

Here is my current workaround solution it does pretty much what I was hoping I could have done with the distribution plugin.

Basically I create an `osType` property and set it's "default" to the os I am developing on, in this case macos.  Then I have all my common dependencies in one dependency closure and add in the the os specific stuff in a groovy switch statement.  I then just coded up a short shell script that overrides the osType property to each of the os's I want to support and calls the gradle task to build each in turn.

Here is my build.gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.2.61'
    id 'application'
}

ext {
    swtVersion = "4.5.2"
}

ext.osType = project.properties['osType'] ?: 'macos'
println "building for ${osType}"

mainClassName = "MainKt"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://maven-eclipse.github.io/maven" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
}

switch(osType) {
    case 'macos':
        dependencies {
            implementation "org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64:${swtVersion}"
        }
        applicationDefaultJvmArgs.push("-XstartOnFirstThread")
        break
    case 'linux':
        dependencies {
            implementation "org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64:${swtVersion}"
        }
        startScripts.doLast {
            def lines = unixScript.text.readLines()
            println lines.add(1, 'export FOO=foo')
            println lines.add(2, 'export BAR=bar')
            unixScript.text = lines.join("\n")
        }
        break
    case 'windows':
        dependencies {
            implementation "org.eclipse.swt:org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64:${swtVersion}"
        }
}

version "${osType}-1.0-SNAPSHOT"

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
```

and here is my shell script (buildAll.sh) that I run from the terminal in Idea.

```
#!/bin/sh
./gradlew -PosType=macos distTar
./gradlew -PosType=linux distTar
./gradlew -PosType=windows distTar
./gradlew -PosType=windows distZip
```